# The resource cannot be found. after adding new page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new MVC4 Web application, and then i am adding new View in views called Login.aspx.

When i try to access it the way i am accessing About.aspx ( which is generated automatically with new project ) - i am receiving "The resource cannot be found." type of error.

- What could cause this issue ?

Comment: Have you defined `action`?

Comment: Show the URL, the Controller and View codes. You shouldn't be accessing a `.aspx` anyway.

Comment: Create an action called "login" that returns "Login.aspx" as a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sole view is not enough in ASP.NET MVC to add a new page to the application. You also have to:

1. Create controller with corresponding action, or add new action to one of existing controllers.
2. Implement this action to return necessary view (Login in your case).
3. Make sure that your action is covered by one of existing routes. If it is not - add a new route.

For details you can review [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-view) on MSDN.

Comment: O Lords!! .. Thank You VERY VERY Much Andrei ! :)